# How to AWK print only specific item?

Tags: awk

I have a log file that looks like this:

```
RPT_LINKS=1,T1999
RPT_NUMALINKS=1
RPT_ALINKS=1,1999TK,2135,2009,31462,29467,2560
RPT_TXKEYED=1
RPT_ETXKEYED=0
```

I have used grep to isolate the line I am interested in with the RPT_ALINKS. In that line I want to know how to use AWK to print only the link that ends with a TK.

I am really close running this:

```
grep -w 'RPT_ALINKS' stats2.log | awk -F 'TK' '{print  FS }'
```

But I am sure those who are smarter than me already know I am getting only the TK back, how do I get the entire field so that I would get a return of 1999TK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only a single RT in that line and RT is always at the end:

```
awk '/RPT_ALINKS/{match($0,/[^=,]*TK/); print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

You can also use a double grep

```
grep -w 'RPT_ALINKS' stats2.log | grep -wo '[^=,]*TK'
```

The following sed solution also works nicely:

```
sed '/RPT_ALINKS/s/\(^.*[,=]\)\([^=,]*TK\)\(,.*\)\?/\2/'
```

Comment: Another great solution, tested and working. Thank you kvantour.

Comment: Yes TK will always be at the end of the string. I did not know a double grep was possible, very cool. Frustrating I can only accept one solution as the answer, they are all great. Yours was selected because I learned and you offered more than one option. Great work!

Comment: The awk script should really be `/^RPT_ALINKS=/ && match($0",",/[^=,]*TK,/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}` to avoid false matches and not print a blank line if no TK value exists. The grep and sed have similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't get any more elegant

```
awk -F '=' '$1=="RPT_ALINKS" {n=split($2,array,",")
            for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
              if (array[i] ~ /TK$/)
                {print array[i]}}
           ' stats2.log
```

> `n=split($2,array,",")`: split `1,1999TK,2135,2009,31462,29467,2560` with `,` to array `array`. `n` contains number of array elements, here 7.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you Cyrus. One more question came to mind while trying to decide how to word the question... Is the '1999TK' considered a column, a field or a variable when using awk?

Comment: Awk uses records and Fields as nomenclature

Comment: It depends on your field separator. I used `=`. `RPT_ALINKS` is then first column and `1,1999TK,2135,2009,31462,29467,2560` second column. Hemang's code used `,` and `=` as field separator. Then row starting with `RPT_ALINKS` splits in eight columns.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution

```
awk -F ',|=' '/^RPT_ALINKS/ { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /TK$/) print $i }' stats2.log
```

It looks only on the record which begins with RPT_ALINKS. And there it check every field. If field ends with TK, then it prints it.

Comment: Also a great response that works perfectly. Probably a couple dozen ways to do this if all the experts were to converge. Yet I know none of them haha... Thank you Hemang, it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Dang, I was just about to post the double-grep alternative, but got scooped. And all the good awk solutions are taken as well.

Sigh. So here we go in bash, for fun.

```
$ mapfile a < stats2.log
$ for i in "${a[@]}"; do [[ $i =~ ^RPT_ALINKS=(.+,)*([^,]+TK) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"; done
1999TK
```

This has the disadvantage of running way slower than awk and not using fields. Oh, and it won't handle multiple `*TK` items on a single line. And like `sed`, this is processing lines as *patterns* rather than *fields*, which saps elegance. And by using mapfile, we limit the size of input you can handle because your whole log is loaded into memory. Of course you don't really need to do that, but if you were going to use a pipe, you'd use a different tool anyway. :-)

Happy Thursday.

Comment: This was tested and works well also.  The ID's are radios and the TK is the unit currently activating the repeater, so there will only ever be one with the TK (transmitting) indicator at a time. Thanks for offering another great solution.

Answer (score 1):

With a sed that has `-E` for EREs, e.g. GNU or OSX/BSD sed:

```
$ sed -En 's/^RPT_ALINKS=(.*,)?([^,]*TK)(,.*|$)/\2/p' file
1999TK
```

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0",",/^RPT_ALINKS=(.*,)?([^,]*TK),.*/,a){print a[2]}' file
1999TK
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through it, you can use an other alternative.
This will be fast, loop takes time.

```
awk -F"TK" '/RPT_ALINKS/ {b=split($1,a,",");print a[b]FS}' stats2.log
1999TK
```

Here you split the line by setting field separator to `TK` and search for line that contains `RPT_ALINKS`
That gives `$1=RPT_ALINKS=1,1999` and `$2=,2135,2009,31462,29467,2560`
`$1` will always after last comma have our value.
So split it up using split function by comma.  `b` would then contain number of fields.
Since we know that number would be in last section we do use `a[b]` and add `FS` that contains `TK`